# Automatically create local copy of hosted feature service and sync

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

does anyone know if its possible to write a python script to automatically create a local copy of a hosted feature service from ArcGIS online in to ArcMap so that it can be modified locally and then synced back to ArcGIS online?
There are no out-of-the-box geoprocessing tools that will create a local copy.
Another solution may be ArcGIS Pro, which hosted feature services can be edited natively. However, i am trying to delete all features/rows within the hosted feature service and append new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its possible, just export your service, do the work that you normally do, and overwrite it.

Another way would be to edit the edit the data itself on the GIS server, and refresh your layer wherever you are using it at some interval.